# SuperController of Getx Package in Flutter causing a problem

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I am facing a problem when I extends a class with SuperController of Getx PAckage in Flutter. Please go through my code and let me know the solution.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/user_status_controller.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  Get.put(UserStatusController());
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
          child: Text(
        'Hello',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

user_status_controller.dart

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class UserStatusController extends SuperController {
  @override
  void onDetached() {}

  @override
  void onInactive() {}

  @override
  void onPaused() {}

  @override
  void onResumed() {}
}
```

The error thrown is:

```
E/flutter ( 3620): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter ( 3620): #0      FullLifeCycleMixin.onInit (package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart:90:28)
E/flutter ( 3620): #1      GetLifeCycleBase._onStart (package:get/get_instance/src/lifecycle.dart:66:5)
E/flutter ( 3620): #2      InternalFinalCallback.call (package:get/get_instance/src/lifecycle.dart:12:26)
E/flutter ( 3620): #3      GetInstance._startController (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:253:16)
E/flutter ( 3620): #4      GetInstance._initDependencies (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:204:11)
E/flutter ( 3620): #5      GetInstance.find (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:301:17)
E/flutter ( 3620): #6      GetInstance.put (package:get/get_instance/src/get_instance.dart:86:12)
E/flutter ( 3620): #7      Inst.put (package:get/get_instance/src/extension_instance.dart:89:21)
E/flutter ( 3620): #8      main (package:flutter_app/main.dart:6:7)
E/flutter ( 3620): #9      _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:129:25)
E/flutter ( 3620): #10     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1428:13)
E/flutter ( 3620): #11     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1328:19)
[GETX] Instance "UserStatusController" has been created
E/flutter ( 3620): #12     _runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1863:10)
E/flutter ( 3620): #13     runZonedGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1851:12)
E/flutter ( 3620): #14     _runMainZoned.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:125:5)
E/flutter ( 3620): #15     _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19)
E/flutter ( 3620): #16     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:12)
```

Could anybody tell me what is throwing the error. Please help me. This is a simple code I'm unable to understand what is causing this.

Comment: have you tried to bind the controller to the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

hmm try this if its working if not mention me

xample your main.dart

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
      getPages: RouteList.routeLists,
      initialRoute: "/home"
    );
  }
}
```

create a binding dart named it binding_home.dart depends on you

```
class YourBinding extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    // TODO: implement dependencies
    Get.lazyPut(() => UserStatusController (), fenix: true);
  }
}
```

then on your route to bind it

```
class RouteList {
  static final routeLists = [
    GetPage(
        transition: Transition.cupertinoDialog,
        transitionDuration: 350.milliseconds,
        name: "/home",
        binding: YourBinding(),
        page: () => const HomePage()),
  ];
}
```

next is your controller

```
class UserStatusController extends SuperController {
  @override
  void onDetached() {}

  @override
  void onInactive() {}

  @override
  void onPaused() {}

  @override
  void onResumed() {}
}
```

then lastly on homepage try use Getview

```
class HomePage extends GetView<UserStatusController > {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
          child: Text(
        'Hello',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

i do sometime it depends use Getview so that i wont put on the stateless like Get.put() or find(). as per default calling on the controller just type controller.yourValue

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `SuperController` you need to call   `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();` on the `main` function of your app:

```
void main(){
     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

     runApp(YourApp());
}
```